# Mixing Top-Alignment in tabular

Tags: tables

I'm at the end of my mind. Why is it not possible to mix the top-alignment in a table?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|p{0.3\textwidth}|c}
ID & Klasse & Beschreibung & Status \\
center & center & top Die Scriping-Umgebung kann zur Laufzeit String-Variablen in Maschinencode übersetzen und ausführen & \Huge\checkmark \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Simply the table columns should be center | center | top | center. But I'm not able the get it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired vertically centered alignment of the single row containing columns, you can use the `m` type column instead of the `p` type column. In the following example, I have also shonwn how to achieve a raggedright alignment on the third column as currently there are quite large spaces between the words.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|m{0.3\textwidth}|c}
ID & Klasse & Beschreibung & Status \\
center & center & top Die Scriping-Umgebung kann zur Laufzeit String-Variablen in Maschinencode übersetzen und ausführen  & \Huge\checkmark \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\begin{table}[h]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|L{0.3\textwidth}|c}
ID & Klasse & Beschreibung & Status \\
center & center & top Die Scriping-Umgebung kann zur Laufzeit String-Variablen in Maschinencode übersetzen und ausführen  & \Huge\checkmark \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

three possibility:

[image]

to my taste i would use the last example. at the firs example it is difficult to see where start new row. but you can select a solution which you like :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|>{\RaggedRight}m{0.35\textwidth}|c}
ID & Klasse & Beschreibung & Status \\
center & center & top Die Scriping-Umgebung kann zur Laufzeit String-Variablen in Maschinencode übersetzen und ausführen & \Huge\checkmark \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.35\textwidth}|c}
ID & Klasse & Beschreibung & Status \\
center & center & top Die Scriping-Umgebung kann zur Laufzeit String-Variablen in Maschinencode übersetzen und ausführen & \Huge\checkmark \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\begin{table}[ht]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.35\textwidth}|c}
ID & Klasse & Beschreibung & Status \\
center & center & top Die Scriping-Umgebung kann zur Laufzeit String-Variablen in Maschinencode übersetzen und ausführen & \multirow{4}{*}{\Huge\checkmark} \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

**addendum:** 
for completeness an improved version of the first solution. to it is added more vertical space around cells' contents in the third column's. for this is used `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, cellspace, multirow}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|>{\RaggedRight}S{m{0.35\textwidth}}|c}
ID & Klasse & Beschreibung & Status \\
center & center & top Die Scriping-Umgebung kann zur Laufzeit String-Variablen in Maschinencode übersetzen und ausführen & \Huge\checkmark \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: stupidly I miss one usecase. Is it also possible to make it like: **top | top | top | center**. In code I try **p{2cm}|p{2cm}|>{\RaggedRight}m{0.35\textwidth}|c** but the p-Column get ignored. :-(

Comment: this case is not possible on such simple way. also from tipographical point of view it hasn't appealing lookout.

Comment: sadly, but thanks @Zarko for your response.